# Servlets: How to log messages from Servlet

Tags: servlets, logging, slf4j

I have one Servlet class and 3/4 java classes which have many methods. The servlet class creates instance of another java class which calls other class method and so on. I need to log all the activity in all classes. But currently only Servlet class I can log that to with system.out.println in server log. I want to use slf4j but how to include logs of all classes could you suggest.

Comment: you might want to read up on log4j library.

Comment: Use slf4j, and that will generate logs, whatever the class containing the logging statements is. You use slf4j the same way, whether your class is a servlet or not. What is your question?